# Installing and Configuring Mumble Server

Tags: server, 14.04, 64-bit, mumble

I'm looking to setup a Mumble Server. I will be running it from an Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) powered VPS provided by DigitalOcean. Setup of the server seems easy, install the murmur package, however it is the configuration that is the problem. I can't seem to find the right guides on the internet to do the full configuration for the rooms, permissions and other things like that. Would anybody be able to explain how to set up a server so it is usable and the permissions aren't screwed to the point in which people can do things they shouldn't be able to do, like ban or kick people.

Thanks in advance.